# Silverlight and ActiveDirectory authentication

Tags: silverlight, authentication, silverlight-4.0

I need to be able to determine who is accessing my silverlight application using ActiveDirectory(AD).

Is this possible?

What are my options?

**Important**: While I realize that the SilverLight app itself is hosted within the context of a web-page that is hosted in IIS and so I could use integrated authentication to control access to the host-webpage, I would like a method that would work directly through Silverlight as the app maybe run in an "Out Of Browser" mode.

Answer (score 1):

Your best method is to have a WCF service provide authentication services to AD, and return a "credential" object back to your SL app based on login credentials.  Course, you could use that same service for your ASP apps, WPF apps, etc.

Comment: Have you got any links to samples?

Answer (score 0):

[ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx) is available. But I am not sure it is available(or supported) in Silverlight

Comment: I can use it within an ASP.Net app, but not in Silverlight.